# UIImageView moved to storyboard position when label text is updated

Tags: swift, uiimageview, position, autolayout, xcode6

There are other posts with my problem but there are no answers posted and they are coding in Objective-C and not swift

([UIImageView Position Resetting during label text update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070010/uiimageview-position-resetting-during-label-text-update))

([when updating label text a few images reset to their storyboard init size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399688/when-updating-label-text-a-few-images-reset-to-their-storyboard-init-size))

My problem is that whenever my program runs this line of code

`self.scoreLabel.text = String(score)`

The UIImageViews located in the same view get reverted back to the position they are on the storyboard. None of the UIImageViews have any constraints on them, and without that line of code everything works fine. When the user moves their player to a certain area and scores a point, the entire story board will basically just reset. I'm pretty sure this has something to do with auto layout, but I was wondering if there is a different way to fix this besides disabling auto layout. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you don't want to disable auto layout you should set constraints.

Comment: I have UIImageViews that move around. If I enable constraints they will just stay in the same place

Comment: I've recently watched this talk: https://realm.io/news/gotocph-marin-todorov-auto-layout-animations-ios/
The point is: if you move some views, you have to alter their constraints, otherwise they will be placed where auto-layout thinks it's correct. Perhaps this helps.