# Disabling Auto Layout removes all images on the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, xcode6

Halfway through my project I realized that I shouldn't be using auto layout. The only problem is that when I disable it, I lose all of the images and such on my storyboard. Is there a way to keep all of the images and the IBOutlets/IBActions that I created, or will I have to do all of that over again?

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn't be using auto layout?

Comment: @rdelmar practically none of my images require constraints, they are all constantly moving. The problem I'm having is that whenever I update my UILabel, it moves all of my UIImageViews back to the location they were placed on the storyboard

Comment: Do mean it does that now after you disabled auto layout or before? When auto layout is on, that is the expected behavior if you moved your image views by setting frames rather than adjusting the constraints (which is what you should do when auto layout is on). Did you also run off size classes?

Comment: @rdelmar It does that with auto layout. I haven't seen what it does after disabling auto layout because then I would have to redo all of my images and IBActions/Outlets. Everything works perfectly until I update the label, I have no constraints on my images. I am not running off size classes. Also here is a link to another post from someone else who has the exact same problem as I, it may help explain the situation a bit better [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070010/uiimageview-position-resetting-during-label-text-update)

Comment: If you haven't turned of auto layout, then you do have constraints on your image views -- the system adds them automatically if you don't add them yourself. IF you want to leave auto layout on, then you should make IBOutlets to all the constraints you need to change, and change their constant values in code. I don't know why you think you will have to redo everything if you turn off auto layout -- that shouldn't have anything to do with your actions or outlets.

Comment: @rdelmar I guess I'll have to try that. Thanks for your help